# Is it grammatical to say "the batmen"?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, grammatical-number, proper-nouns

As far as I know, the five actors to have played the role of Batman in films are Adam West, Michael Keaton, Val Kilmer, George Clooney, and Christian Bale. Is it grammatical to call them "the batmen"?

Comment: *batmen* with a small B is a perfectly normal word, but unfortunately has nothing to to with Bruce Wayne (in a military context, it refers to soldier-servants). So if you do wish to use the word, you need to retain the capital letter.

Comment: @Tim _batmen_ aren't the multiple older batboys at a baseball game?

Comment: If it is grammatical, you'd really want to capitalize it: " __B__ atmen ".

Comment: I like the Spanish convention for referring to members of a family: the plural masculine article, followed by the (unpluralized) family name.  So:  **los Batman**.

Comment: Two Batmens? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PETk8eBbfN0

Comment: At this point, there have been eight: https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/48823/46782

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would say that strictly speaking it is not. Irregular plurals carry if they are instances of the base word. A "fireman" is a type of man, so "firemen" is the appropriate plural, but the "Toronto Maple Leafs" are not leaves.

Since *Batman* is a proper noun, *Batman* does not designate a type of man but the name for one particular man, so the irregular plural does not carry. It should be "the Batmans". However, this is, at least to my ear, somewhat awkward.

So you have three choices. If you want to be strictly correct and not be awkward, "the actors who portrayed Batman". If you don't mind being a bit awkward, "the Batmans". If you can tolerate a few points off on your poetic license, and can see *Batman* as not so much a proper noun but as a type of man, then why not ... "the Batmen".

Comment: I don't think _the Batmans_ is awkward. People didn't have any problem referring to _Sony Walkmans_.

Comment: @alcas: True, that's not awkward at all. (Though Sony didn't like it, insisting one should say "Walkman personal entertainment devices".) I toned down my description of *the Batmans* as awkward.

Comment: But the plural ["pop flies" is used.](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22pop+flies%22+baseball&hl=en&gbv=2&revid=143026813&gs_l=heirloom-serp.3..0i22.16219.25566.0.25842.14.14.0.0.0.0.149.1508.5j9.14.0...0.0...1c.1.CJ6ONgtE66w&oq=%22pop+flies%22+baseball)

Comment: hm... I think all that indicates is that, since _pop flys_ and _pop flies_ would be pronounced the same, people are more likely to use the regular spelling. It's not a very illustrative example for that reason. Things like _Sony Walkmans_ or the _Toronto Maple Leafs_ (not _Walkmen_ or _Maple Leaves_) better illustrate the point. IIRC, these are so-called "headless compounds": _man_ is not the head of the compound _Walkman_ (i.e. a Walkman is not a type of man) so _Walkman_ follows regular pluralization rules, not the irregular one followed by _man_.

Comment: Very nice, +1 now :)

Comment: @David Schwartz: the plural _mouses_ is allowable for the electronic device (AHDEL) though not the rodent (except perhaps in _The Muppets' Christmas Carol_), though I think your claim about irregular plurals holding with compounds is generally true.

Comment: @alcas, Google Ngrams indicate that you’re right about _Sony Walkmans_, though I have to say that to me, that both looks and sounds absolutely preposterous. I would never dream of pluralising _walkman_ as anything but _walkmen_, and I’m quite I’d stumble if I heard anyone using _walkmans_ in conversation. Similarly, _the Batmen_ sounds perfectly normal and immediately understandable to me, while _the Batmans_ sounds frightfully awkward and unnatural.

Comment: Thing is, *walkman* is not a man. I'd think a box of action figures of the Superman could be called a box of *Supermans*, but an eugenics supporter's aim is to create *supermen*.

Answer (score 7):

You could write *the batmen*, and if you’re writing an attention-getting headline, maybe you should. But it is definitely unusual enough to call attention to itself, and you typically don’t want to distract the reader from what you’re trying to say.

*Batmans* sounds obviously wrong to me, unless you’re going for laughs. Cf. [*librarymans*](http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2007/08/03).

For what it’s worth, there is an actual episode of an actual Batman-themed TV show titled [“Night of the Batmen!”](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/The_Night_of_the_Batmen!). Apparently the [Batmen of All Nations](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batmen_of_All_Nations) are a thing too.

Maybe it’s just me but it seems like real sentences using *batmen* tend to be a bit informal in tone:

> *The result was 3 pages of Batmen in their off-hours, when they’re just kicking back and taking a break from being the Batmen we all know and love.*

while those using *batmans* are **extremely** informal in tone:

> *I freely admit I love ALL THE BATMANS.*
>
> *i think the batmans weapons cannot even harm iron man as he withstands powerful missiles.so ironman wins the game.*
>
> *All “decent” actors when giving the approriate character… but not in this type of movie…. maybe in the batmans of the 90’s…*

Comment: We would, of course, have both supermen and Supermans.

Comment: @Edwin: Let's not forget about Wonder Womans.

Comment: Well, your second-to-last example is just somebody forgetting to put an apostrophe in the possessive.

Comment: The first ‘Batmans’ example is a case of the Internet meme _all the [plural]_, which always uses a regular (or even doubled regular) plural, even if ungrammatical. “I want all the moneys”, “I had all the feels”, “I love all the womanses”. An irregular plural just does not occur in this construction. The second is a missing apostrophe, as alcas says. The third, to me, uses a regular plural because it is a plural of the _movies_, not the characters. There have been different _Romeos_ and _Juliets_ in the _Romeo and Juliets_ of the 20th century, and different _Batmen_ in the _Batmans_ of the 90s.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is grammatical.
Batman, UK noun, plural Batmen.
The [personal servant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_%28military%29) of an officer especially in the British Armed Forces

Answer (score 4):

No. Batman is a single character. Multiple actors have played the character, but there's only one Batman.

Comment: In this case I read "Batmans" in the sense of "Batman portrayals" given the OP's examples. As in opera we could write about great Figaros.

Comment: +1 for pointing out what should be obvious. There is one fictional character called Batman, so 'Batmen' is not even logical, never mind grammatical. The OP list five Batman actors, not five 'batmen'.

Answer (score 2):

**Batman** is the name of a character. Philip Seymor Hoffman played *Truman Capote* in the movie *Capote*. In referring to this character, if there were remake, the various portrayals would not be *Trumen*.

It is conceivable that the various players collectively *could* be referred to as the *Trumans*, but that feels very artificial. Each of the actors would have played *Truman* and collectively they played *Truman* or the *Truman roles*.

While it is arguable that there have been many *Othellos*, I think it is much better form to indicate that many have been *Othello*, that is, when referring to character names, the plural should be avoided. (Perhaps the only exception is a mulitplicity of *Elvises* and only when they appear in multiples at the same time, such as in *[Honeymoon in Vegas](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104438/plotsummary)*.)

Comment: _Truman_ isn’t really a good parallel, since it is not an obvious compound. Historically, the last part is ‘man’, but synchronically, _Truman_ is just a name, and it is pronounced /ˈtruːm(ə)n/, not /ˈtruːˌmæn/. _Batman_, on the other hand, is a synchronic compound: it is very much ‘the Bat Man’, and unlike the regular noun ‘batman’, the name is always pronounced /ˈbætˌmæn/, never /ˈbætm(ə)n/.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think you are probably right that Truman is a bad analogy. My view remains since there is no species of *batmen* but only a series, taken one at a time, of *Batman*.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, there have not *been* multiple "Batmen," but rather "multiple portrayals of Batman." Not only is it not grammatical to say "the batmen," it is factually incorrect to refer to the actors as such. Certainly, it's an appealing construction - after all, it sort of rolls off the tongue. However, that's not the nature of acting.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the number of [actors who have portrayed Batman](http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/21717/the-7-actors-who-have-played-batman) is seven not five.  Lewis G Wilson; Robert Lowrey; Adam West; Michael Keaton; Val Kilmer; George Clooney and Christian Bale.

Note the author of the article (and also the OP) wrote *Batman* and nothing similar to "There have been seven *Batmen* in the TV series  and movie history." The noun *batmen* is of course grammatical, but why shouldn't it be? The plural of *man* is *men*, and as [@Jrfras](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/152173/44619) mentioned in their post, *batmen* are the personal servants assigned to a commissioned officer in the British Armed Forces. Therefore the following sentences would be perfectly correct

> Yesterday police arrested ***a batman***.
>   and
>   Yesterday police arrested ***several batmen***.

However, the nouns *Batman* and *Caped Crusader* are both *proper nouns* and it is the norm in English to capitalize proper nouns. Some proper nouns can be pluralized when we mention them as ***a unique group*** for example; *the Simpsons*, *the Bushes*, *the Marches*, *the Himalayas*; *the United States*; *the Yankees*; *the Green Bay Packers* etc.

But the role of **Batman** is one, the superhero in every film, comic strip, TV series is one, there has never been seven "Batmen" simultaneously. The seven actors are never referred to as "the Batmen" or, *ex-Batmen*. If two or more were called *Batmen* the term would be ambiguous, the speaker/writer might be stating that the actors were once private soldiers who were servants to high ranking officers.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_%28military%29#United_Kingdom) mentions in its article *Batman (military)*

> J. R. R. Tolkien took the relationship of his characters Samwise Gamgee and Frodo Baggins from his observations while in military service during World War I of the relationship between a batman and his officer
>
> Popular ITV drama Downton Abbey featured a valet named Bates who
>   served Lord Grantham as a batman in the Boer War.
>
> In the BBC sitcom Blackadder Goes Forth, set during World War I, actor
>   Tony Robinson portrays Private S. Baldrick, the bumbling and
>   incompetent batman to Captain Edmund Blackadder.

Google Books [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+batmen%2Cis+batman%2Cis+Batman%2Care+Batmen%2Cwere+batmen%2Cwere+Batmen%2Cwas+Batman%2Cwas+batman&year_start=1900&year_end=2005&corpus=17&smoothing=2&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20batman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20Batman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20Batman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20batman%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20batman%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20Batman%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20Batman%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20batman%3B%2Cc1) seem to suggest that the plural forms "are/were batmen" and "are/were Batmen" are non-existent in American English whereas the expressions "was/is batman" enjoyed its peak of usage between 1916 and 1920, and the *proper noun* "was/is Batman" has had the upper hand since the 1960s.

[image]

The only group of superheroes I can think of whose name terminates with *men* is...

### [X-men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men)

> Within the Marvel Universe, the X-Men are widely regarded to have
>   been named after Professor Xavier himself. Xavier however claims that
>   the name "X-Men" was never chosen to be a self-tribute. [...] The
>   original explanation for the name, as provided by Xavier, is that
>   mutants "possess an extra power... one which ordinary humans do not!!
>   That is why I call my students... X-Men, for EX-tra power!".

Comment: The Watchmen are definitely superheroes and the members of the League of Extraordinary Gentlemen arguably are as well. Coincidentally, both were written by Alan Moore.

Answer (score 1):

On August 2, 2014, the *New York Times* published an article titled "Spider-Man Unmasked! Elmo and Minnie, Too" about people who dress up as cartoon characters in order to pose for pictures and receive tips from tourists in Times Square—and this very question came up, not in the context of multiple instances of Batman but of multiple instances of Spider-Man. Here is how the *New York Times* handled the issue:

> The performers have come under even greater pressure since a recent violent confrontation between a man dressed as **Spider-Man** and a police officer. The man was arrested after fighting with the officer, who had responded to the man’s aggressive solicitation, the authorities said.
>
> The episode was the latest in a recent series of unpleasant encounters that have cast a cloud over the street performers. Two other **Spider-Men** were arrested in separate episodes in June, one charged with groping a woman and the other charged with assaulting a woman (he was found not guilty but was fined for harassment).

A caption in the same story mentions "the Times Square hurly-burly of Elmos, Minnie Mouses and **Batmen** who pose for photographs and then coax customers for tips." On the other hand, the same story also cites "an enclave of Mickey Mouses and Sheriff Woodys" (Sheriff Woody being the name of a character from the *Toy Story* movies)—but if you take *Spider-Man/Spider-Men* and *Batman/ Batmen*, instead of *Spider-Man/Spider-Mans* and *Batman/Batmans*,  I would have expected the Sheriff Woody pairing to be *Sheriff Woody/Sheriff Woodies*, not *Sheriff Woody/Sheriff Woodys*.

Its hard to avoid the conclusion that the *New York Times*'s treatment of *Spider-Men* (on the one hand) and its treatment of *Sheriff Woodys* (on the other) represent inconsistent ways of handling the same problem of rendering a singular proper (but fictional) name as a plural.

Comment: From the first paragraph it's clear the article is not about the superhero Spiderman or the actors in the franchise, but about "ordinary" people who *dressed as* Spiderman, Elmo, Minnie Mouse (not mice?:-)), Sheriff Woody etc.

Answer (score 0):

A name, proper noun, or a character.
But **Batmen** sounds right .

Two examples from a **UK** based newspaper :

The gathering of 542 **Batmen** (and women) kicked off a campaign for a United Way charity.

In this short film released to commemorate Batman’s 75th birthday, old man Bruce Wayne and Terry McGinnis fight against the Dark Knight’s past incarnations – **Batmen** from comics, cartoons and live action. Happy Birthday, **Bats**!

What about **Bats**......

Answer (score 0):

**Batmen** is grammatically correct, and the contextual meaning will probably be understood by the reader.

Whether or not you would use the word is more about style and preference. You could avoid the word by writing "the actors who've played Batman" or you could be lighthearted and use "Bat-Thespians" for example to go with naming convention of Batman's tools.