# How to pluralize a last name like Thomas

Tags: punctuation

If I am addressing a card to multiple family members with the last name Thomas, is the correct spelling Thomas's or Thomas'?

Comment: Bus:buses :: Thomas:Thomases.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: *[Pluralization of names](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39150)*; *[Family name pluralization](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7469)*; and *[Pluralization of proper nouns: regular or irregular?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81522)*

Comment: Collectively, **Mr Thomas's family** would be referred to as **The Thomases**

Answer (score 6):

The identical question was asked on [this forum 12 years ago](http://forums.anandtech.com/archive/index.php/t-940538.html), right down to the name used:

> Thomases. An apostrophe denotes ownership or a contraction.
>
> Examples of correct uses:
>
> I'm visiting the Thomases. That is Thomas' chair. That's the Thomases'
>   dog. The construction "Thomas's" is wrong.
>
> "Apostrophes are NEVER ever used to make plurals."
>   (http://www.spotlight-online.de/CoCoCMS/generator/viewDocument.php?doc=4279)
>   "Apostrophes are NOT used for possessive pronouns or for noun
>   plurals."
>   (http://owl.english.purdue.edu/handouts/grammar/g_apost.html)
>
> from the MLA handbook, 5th ed.:
>
> To form the possessive of a plural proper noun, add only an
>   apostrophe.
>
> [examples:] the Vanderbilts' estate the Dickenses' economic woes
>
> last linky (http://webster.commnet.edu/grammar/plurals.htm)
>
> When a family name (a proper noun) is pluralized, we almost always
>   simply add an "s." So we go to visit the Smiths, the Kennedys, the
>   Grays, etc.When a family name ends in s, x, ch, sh, or z, however, we
>   form the plural by added -es, as in the Marches, the Joneses, the
>   Maddoxes, the Bushes, the Rodriguezes. Do not form a family name
>   plural by using an apostrophe; that device is reserved for creating
>   possessive forms.

Comment: Apostrophes can be used for plurals of single letters: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25277/what-is-the-proper-way-to-write-the-plural-of-a-single-letter-another-apostrop

Comment: 'The possessive "Thomas's" is wrong.' One view. An overview is given at [dailywritingtips.com](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/possessive-of-proper-names-ending-in-s/): 'Most stylebooks agree that the rule for forming the possessive of a singular noun ending in -s is formed by adding ’s:

the boss’s birthday
the bus’s wheels
the witness’s testimony

**When it comes to forming the possessive of a proper name that ends in s, guides disagree.**'

Comment: The construction "Thomas's" is correct if "Thomas" is referring to a *single* person.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing to the Thomas family (or family Thomas, to be a little jazzy) or to the individual or multiple Thomases who comprise the family. Most surnames form the plural using the same rules as for other nouns.