# How do I refer to multiple people with the same name

Tags: apostrophe, proper-nouns, irregular-plurals

My daughter now has her own bedroom.  She doesn't want her sister to come in.  She has made a sign.

> "No Paiges Allowed!"

What is the correct apostrophy use on "Paiges" when I want to refer to multiple people of the same name?

EDIT: Follow up question: what if it was "No Chrisss Allowed!"?

Comment: Apostrophes have no place in simple plurals. Apostrophes are only for when letters are omitted, and for possessives (but not possessive pronouns).

Comment: If the name is "Paige" your quote is correct.

Comment: You asked "EDIT: Follow up question: what if it was "No Chrisss Allowed!"?" I have not seen the name "Chriss", but the plural is Chrisses - Compare Lioness -> Lionesses.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/304621/191178